# How to manipulate a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have the following sample dataframe:

[image]

I need to transform it to look like :

[image]

Pls note that:

- In the new column, the last 2 columns in original data frame have been replaced by the district variables of second last column of original df
- The original df was duplicating columns upto 'Year' column and the new df should have fewer rows because the new variables are now in a 'transposed manner'

What I had thought would work out never did. Because the rows are still duplicated:

```
print(PopRatesC.shape)
PopRates = PopRatesC.copy()
PopRates.rename(columns={'Value':'PopRate'}, inplace=True)
PopRates=pd.get_dummies(data=PopRates, columns=['Series'])
PopRates['Rural_PopRate']= PopRates['Series_Rural_Rate']*PopRates['PopRate']
PopRates['Urban_PopRate']= PopRates['Series_Urban_Rate']*PopRates['PopRate']
print(PopRates.shape)
PopRates[416:422]
```

[image: my output]

Kindly explain the right approach I should use.

Comment: On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you wanna get a pivot based on group of columns, so simply use [`pandas.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'code': [108,108,108,108,132,132],
    'country': ['burundi','burundi','burundi','burundi','cabo verde','cabo verde'],
    'year': [2010,2010,2015,2015,2005,2005],
    'series': ['urban_rate','rural_rate','urban_rate','rural_rate','urban_rate','rural_rate'],
    'value': [5.9,3.0,5.6,2.7,3.3,-0.2]
})

pd.pivot(df, index=['code','country','year'], columns='series', values='value').reset_index()
```

###### Output

| code | country | year | rural_rate | urban_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | burundi | 2010 | 3.0 | 5.9 |
| 108 | burundi | 2015 | 2.7 | 5.6 |
| 132 | cabo verde | 2005 | -0.2 | 3.3 |